# SQL loop with python and pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, ipython, pyodbc

I want to create a query loop, which do interativ steps from one instance to the next. After fetching the right data i will do some calculation and write the new information back in the date base with specific relations.

```
Example Set up
Firt loop = [Aggregation Level](1, 2, 3)
Second loop = Product(A, B, C)
Time = (2001,2002,2003)

1. First loop 
Aggregation level "1", Product "A", Fetch all years (2001, 2002, 2003)
Output = [
(2001,'10 pc','20 €')
(2002,'8 pc','18 €')
(2003,'82 pc','5000 €')]

2. Second loop
Aggregation level "1", Product "B", Fetch all years (2001, 2002, 2003)
Output = [
(2001,'15 pc','35 €')
(2002,'20 pc','100 €')
(2003,'25 pc','5000 €')]
```

I will use the array (row) and do some calculation. Therefore I will transform the data in a specifc structure after this i will get new figures.

In the end I poste my code and I want to use instead of varible *[X, Y]* in the select statement the index of the imported excel files as loop parameter or is it better to search inside the data base? 
The information already stored in data base.

The variable *[X1, Y1]* are my new values, which must be written back in the data base with a specific relations, how should I do that to get the right relationship? Primary key or better ways?

Wishes
123GuteLaune

```js
import pyodbc as py
import openpyxl as ol

#Connection string to access
cnxn = py.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes#;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\xxx\Desktop;DBQ=C:\xxx\Desktop\DatabaseMA_Test.mdb")

#Connection string to excel
wb = ol.load_workbook('C:\xxx\Desktop\Beisspieldatensatz.xlsx')
X = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Hierarchie")
tuple(X['A2':'A72']).value

wb = ol.load_workbook('C:\xxx\Desktop\Beisspieldatensatz.xlsx')
Y = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Mat_GR")
tuple(Y['A2':'A51']).value

#Output of the loaded Excel data
print (X,Y)

#Load Data out of MS Access
cursor.execute(
               """
               SELECT Mat_ID, Monat, Jahr, Umsatzmenge, Umsatz
               FROM [TW-DS]
               Order BY Jahr ASC 'this is at the moment not working'
               WHERE Hier_ID = ? 
               and Mat_ID= ?
               """, [X, Y])

    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)

    #Mathematical model unfilled

    #Write data back in MS Access
    cursor.execute(
                   """insert into [TW-DS]
                   (Outlier,
                   [Outlier Value])
                   Values 
                   (X1, 
                   Y2)
                   """)
    cnxn.commit()
```